# I am using a low end laptop to learn flutter using web and an android device. Are there any ways to speed up the build process?

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

I am using a 2 gb ram intel core i3 vaio laptop with vscode to learn flutter. I am using adb to connect to my android device. My laptop is taking a very long time for the build process. Are there any tips to speed up the build process as I don't have the budget to upgrade my setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't already, switch to an ARCH Linux distribution. That will cause less of a background strain on your hardware, especially if you're currently on Windows.

Other than that, try to slowly update the laptop starting with the RAM. 8gb should be fine. Depending on your drives, upgrading to an SSD may improve performance as well.

Answer (score 0):

Its very difficult to increase speed but there is way to increase speed i.e use linux(recommend linux that uses less ram) instead of windows.But speedd is less to use flutter in it also but it better than windows